# Retrieve unknown values based on non-schema specific sequence of column values

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to return and operate on time values based on their related event values, but only if a specific sequence of events occurs. A simplified example table below:

```
+--------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+
|   id   |   event1   | time1 |   event2    | time2 |   event3    | time3 |   event4    | time4 |   event5    | time5 |
+--------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| abc123 | firstevent | 10:00 | secondevent | 10:01 | thirdevent  | 10:02 | fourthevent | 10:03 | fifthevent  | 10:04 |
| abc123 | thirdevent | 10:10 | secondevent | 10:11 | thirdevent  | 10:12 | firstevent  | 10:13 | secondevent | 10:14 |
| def456 | thirdevent | 10:20 | firstevent  | 10:21 | secondevent | 10:22 | thirdevent  | 10:24 | fifthevent  | 10:25 |
+--------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

For this table we want to retrieve the times whenever this particular sequence of events occurs: `firstevent`, `secondevent`, `thirdevent`, and a final event of any non-zero value. Meaning the relevant entries returned would be the following:

```
+--------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+------------+-------+
|   id   |   event1   | time1 |   event2    | time2 |   event3    | time3 |   event4    | time4 |   event5   | time5 |
+--------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+------------+-------+
| abc123 | firstevent | 10:00 | secondevent | 10:01 | thirdevent  | 10:02 | fourthevent | 10:03 | null       | null  |
| null   | null       | null  | null        | null  | null        | null  | null        | null  | null       | null  |
| def456 | null       | null  | firstevent  | 10:21 | secondevent | 10:22 | thirdevent  | 10:24 | fifthevent | 10:26 |
+--------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------+------------+-------+
```

As shown above the columns are irrelevant to the occurrence of the sequence, with two results being returned starting in both the `event1` and `event2` columns, thus the solution should be independent and support n number of columns. These values can then be aggregated by the final non-zero event that occurs in the sequence after the 3 fixed variables to give something like the following:

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+
| FinalEvent  | AverageTimeBetweenFinalEvents |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
| fourthevent | 1:00                          |
| fifthevent  | 2:00                          |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the query you have so far?

Comment: @mtr.web Honestly I don't really know where to start, I was hoping to find something akin to the LEAD function but for columns rather than rows, although I can't seem to find anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH search_events AS (
  SELECT ['firstevent', 'secondevent', 'thirdevent'] search
), temp AS (
  SELECT *, REGEXP_EXTRACT(events, CONCAT(search, r',(\w*)')) FinalEvent
  FROM (
    SELECT id, [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5] times,
      (SELECT STRING_AGG(event) FROM UNNEST([event1, event2, event3, event4, event5]) event) events,
      (SELECT STRING_AGG(search) FROM UNNEST(search) search) search
    FROM `project.dataset.table`, search_events 
  )
)
SELECT FinalEvent, 
  times[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(events, CONCAT(r'(.*?)', search, ',', FinalEvent )), ',')) + 3)] time
FROM temp
WHERE IFNULL(FinalEvent, '') != ''
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row FinalEvent  time     
1   fourthevent 10:03    
2   fifthevent  10:25
```

So, as you can see  - all final events are extracted along with their respective times
Now, you can do here whatever analytics you need  - I was not sure about logic behind `AverageTimeBetweenFinalEvents`, so I am leaving this to you - especially that I think that main focus of the question was extraction of those final events

> would you be able to provide the logic behind this statement please?
>    `times[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(events, CONCAT(r'(.*?)', search, ',', FinalEvent )), ',')) + 3)] time`

Sure, hope below helps to get a logic behind that expression

[image]

1. assemble regular expression to extract list of events happened before matched events
2. extract those events
3. extract all commas into array
4. calculate position of final event by taking number of commas in above array + 3 (three is to reflect number of positions in search sequence)
5. extract respective time as an element of times array

Comment: This works great, what I was hoping to achieve with the `AverageTimeBetweenFinalEvents` was to take the timestamp of the final event from the timestamp of the penultimate event to get a numerical value, then take the mean of that across all the instances of the finalevent.

Comment: Also if it's not too much trouble, would you be able to provide the logic behind this statement please?

`times[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_EXTRACT(events, CONCAT(r'(.*?)', search, ',', FinalEvent )), ',')) + 3)] time`

Comment: sure, see addition in my answer